# Angular 6 migration PWA not working

Tags: angular5, angular6

I have recently migrated my app to Angular 6, it was working fine in angular 5, I faced a lot of issues but anyhow I resolved them, but PWA I am not able to migrate,  in angular 5 PWA was working fine, but in 6 Giving below error ...

when I am running

```
    command ng add @angular/PWA  its showing error 
**Error ** 
    target is not defined for the specified project
```

Please help how to migrate or add PWA in Angular 6

Comment: Looks like you are missing the project parameter. According to the docs it is `ng add  @angular/pwa --project *project-name*` https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/bfad6b4fa150f0db7ab30cbe05f5765962a077ce/aio/content/guide/service-worker-getting-started.md

Comment: The above comment also works as the solution, but you can `cd` to your angular project's root and run `ng add` command.

Answer (score 7):

This was already answered in the comment, but since this was the correct solution here's again what to do:

```
ng add @angular/pwa --project *project-name*
```

The above command adds the *@angular/service-worker* package to your **project**.

Source: [Adding a service worker to your project](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/aio/content/guide/service-worker-getting-started.md#adding-a-service-worker-to-your-project)